# Why print won't print?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on an assignment and my prints won't print, even if the rest of the programs runs perfectly.

The function I'm calling is the following:

```
def t4p1(s):
    a,da,b,db,sig=adj.squaremin(adj.getTable(s),univsig=False)
    print 'Hola!'
    print ' a:',a,' da:',da,' b:',b,' db:',db,' sig:',sig
    plot2(adj.getTable(s),chav=False)
    a,da,b,db,sig=adj.squaremin(adj.chaveunet(adj.getTable(s)),univsig=False)
    print ' a:',a,' da:',da,' b:',b,' db:',db,' sig:',sig
    plot2(adj.getTable(s),chav=True)
    print pearson(adj.getTable(s))
```

where a, da, b, db and sigma are correctly defined floats (as I'm using them to plot), and pearson returns also a float. I thought it may be some problem with t4p1() itself, but then I entered the following on the console:

```
In [4]: def heg():
   ...:     print 2

In [5]: heg()

In [6]: print 2
```

and no Out was given.

EDIT:

I reloaded Spyder and everything goes fine with my prints and all, until I run the effing code. Then no print will work on the IPython Console.

If I use the main Python Console, my plots just stick together, but the prints work just fine.

Comment: Are you redirecting stdout somewhere?

Comment: I don't even know what that is (to redirect a stdout)

Comment: All the code that you included is irrelevant. `print 2` does not display anything - that's the real problem. What do you use to develop your program? Which OS? Which IDE?

Comment: I'm running Python 2.7 on Spyder on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I suggest that you close Spyder, start it again and make sure that `print 2` works. Do not load any files or run any other code.

Comment: The IPython Console just crashed, and Spyder raised an Internal Error: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/tmp/spyder-fabrizzio/kernel-f83c6220399f.stderr'

The Python console appears to run just fine.

Comment: I'm editing with something I found out about the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I could not print was because I had the following lines in my code.

```
import sys  
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Now I can't print my 'ñ', but everything else's just fine.